# Birt Report - IReportEngineFactory is null

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, birt

I'm using BIRT without problem on Eclipses but my new company using IntelliJ IDEA.

Using project with Gradle

```
compile files('src/main/resources/lib/flute-1.3.jar') 
compile(group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', name: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', version: '4.4.2') { exclude(group: 'org.milyn', module: 'flute') }
```

I got no problem when running local via main method. But after compile project via

```
shadowJar { 
      classifier = null 
      version = version 
      manifest { 
             attributes 'Main-Class': 'io.vertx.core.Starter'
             attributes 'Main-Verticle': 'other.app.App' 
      } 
      mergeServiceFiles { 
             include 'META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory' 
      } 
}
```

I got null on

```
IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
```

Trying to dig this problem around for a week, I still can't find a solution. Anyone have any suggestion? Tysm for reading.

My code on it:

```
 @Override
    public void generateUserInformationPdf(JsonObject payload) {

        try {

            LOGGER.info("Starting render User Information");

            /* begin get parameters */

            CommonRequest request = gson.fromJson(payload, CommonRequest.class);

            UserPdfPrint userInformation = gson.fromJson(request.getData(), UserPdfPrint.class);

            String p_username = userInformation.getUsername();
            String p_customername = userInformation.getCustomerName();
            String p_dob = userInformation.getDob();
            String p_license = userInformation.getLicense();
            String p_licensedate = userInformation.getLicenseDate();
            String p_licenseplace = userInformation.getLicensePlace();
            String p_sex = userInformation.getSex();
            String p_customerphone = userInformation.getCustomerPhone();
            String p_email = userInformation.getEmail();
            int p_licensetype = userInformation.getLicenseType();


            /* end get parameters section */

            /* load report design */
            String reportName = config.getReportUserInformation();
            IReportEngine engine = null;
            IReportRunnable design = null;

            URL url = null;
            url = new URL(config.getReportFontConfig());

            engineConfig = new EngineConfig();
            engineConfig.setEngineHome("ReportEngine");
            engineConfig.setLogConfig(null, Level.FINE);
            engineConfig.setFontConfig(url);

            Platform.startup(engineConfig);

            IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
                    .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);

            engine = factory.createReportEngine(engineConfig);

            design = engine
                    .openReportDesign(config.getReportTemplatePath()
                            + "/" + reportName); // report

            /* end load report design */

            /* begin render report */
            IRunAndRenderTask task = null;
            PDFRenderOption renderContext = null;
            HashMap contextMap = null;

            task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
            renderContext = new PDFRenderOption();
            contextMap = new HashMap();
            contextMap.put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_HTML_RENDER_CONTEXT,
                    renderContext);
            contextMap.put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", config.getDbConnection());
            task.setAppContext(contextMap);

            task.setParameterValue("p_username", p_username);
            task.setParameterValue("p_customername", p_customername);
            task.setParameterValue("p_dob", p_dob);
            task.setParameterValue("p_license", p_license);
            task.setParameterValue("p_licensedate", p_licensedate);
            task.setParameterValue("p_licenseplace", p_licenseplace);
            task.setParameterValue("p_sex", p_sex);
            task.setParameterValue("p_licensetype", String.valueOf(p_licensetype));
            task.setParameterValue("p_email", p_email);
            task.setParameterValue("p_customerphone", p_customerphone);
            task.validateParameters();

            String random = Generator.generateRandomNumber();

            String today = DateTimes.getCurrentDate().toString();

            String parsedToDate = DateTimes.parseDate(today, "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").toString();

            String toDateString = DateTimes.parseDate(parsedToDate, "dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss").toString();

            String reportNameInFolder = "UserInformation" + toDateString
                    + random;

            String outPutFile = config.getReportOutputPath() + reportNameInFolder + ".pdf";

            PDFRenderOption options = null;
            options = new PDFRenderOption();
            options.setOutputFormat("pdf");
            options.setOutputFileName(outPutFile);

            task.setRenderOption(options);
            task.run();

            System.out.println("All went well. Closing program!");

            /* end render report */

            engine.destroy();
            task.close();
            options.closeOutputStreamOnExit(true);

            mqAdapter.pushToMQ(Transformers.toVertxJsonObject(new EnhancedSuccessResponse()
                    .setHeader(request.getHeader())
                    .setCodes(CodeResponse.SuccessCode.PRINT_PDF_REGISTER_SUCCESS.getCode())
                    .setData(gson.toJsonTree(new PdfReportResponse().setPdfLink(config.getReportOutputLink() + reportNameInFolder + ".pdf")))).encode(), QueueKeys.OtherQueue.ADMIN_GENERATE_USER_INFORMATION_PDF.getValue());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to get Font Config URL. {}", e.toString());
        } catch (BirtException e1) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to start config. {}", e1.toString());
//            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (
                Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to get design template. {}", e.toString());
            System.err
                    .println("An error occured while running the report!");
            LOGGER.error("An error occured while running the report! {}", e.toString());
//            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly how you build the application and run it when it does not work.

Comment: @Andrey

shadowJar a file and run via postman

and i got factory nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Update the build gradle and add

> "flute-1.3.jar" &
>   "org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb-2.10.1.v20130422-1135.jar"

in ***lib*** folder.

```
//Start of birt
    compile(group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', name: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', version: '4.4.2') {
        exclude(group: 'org.milyn', module: 'flute')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', module: 'org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb')
    }
    //End of birt
```

Comment: i did, you can see on top of my post xD and i found out 

"BIRT will not work in a "fat" jar because of OSGI, so Maven shade plugin cannot be used and a zip file must be constructed to be uploaded to Lambda."

from https://github.com/innoventsolutions/birt-lambda-report-gen :(